# Is it necessary to use IO when importing a foreign function that allocates?

Tags: haskell, allocation, ffi

In Haskell, when using the FFI to bind to a function that allocates,
is it appropriate to *avoid* using `IO` when the foreign function allocates
for and constructs some value, and that value *only* depends on the function arguments?

Consider the following function:

```
/**
 * The foo_create contract: if allocation succeeds, the
 * return value points to a value that depends only on 'x'
 * and 'name', otherwise a null pointer is returned.
 */
foo_t *foo_create(int x, const char *name);
```

Would it be appropriate to import this function in the following way?

```
newtype Foo = Foo (Ptr Foo)

foreign import unsafe "foo.h foo_create"
foo_create :: CInt -> CString -> Ptr Foo
```

This low-level binding function can then be wrapped to provide
a nicer API:

```
makeFoo :: CInt -> CString -> Maybe Foo
makeFoo x s =
  let
    ptr = foo_create x s
  in
    if ptr == nullPtr
      then Nothing
      else Just (Foo ptr)
```

Although the allocation affects the real world, and whether or not it succeeds is also dependent on the real world, the type does model the
possible outcomes.  Furthermore, even pure functions and data can cause
the Haskell runtime to allocate.  So, is it reasonable
to avoid the `IO` monad in situations such as these?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If `foo_create` returns a value that only depends on the values of `x` and `name`, then yes it's fine return value outside `IO`. As you say, creating new values inside Haskell causes allocation, and they don't need to be in `IO` because it's impossible to observe the particular memory addresses that get allocated outside of `IO`, and also impossible to observe *whether or not an allocation succeeds* (i.e. whether the program is running out of memory) outside of `IO`.

However, you say "whether or not it succeeds is also dependent on the real world". In that case, no, it is an effectful operation which should have a return type in `IO`. A Haskell function with a type `makeFoo :: CInt -> CString -> Maybe Foo` says that whether the `Maybe Foo` is `Nothing` or `Just _` must depend *only* on the values of the `CInt` and the `CString`. This is every bit as important as that the value inside the `Just` only depends on the arguments.

If it's possible to call a function with the same arguments and get different results depending on the state of the real world, then it isn't a function at all, and should be an `IO` action.

Comment: That makes sense.  Seems obvious in hindsight!  Cheers.